# Ubuntu 64-bit stuck on the purple loading screen on VM

Tags: boot, system-installation, virtualbox, 64-bit

I am currently using a 64-bit PC, with Windows 7 Ultimate as the host OS. and Ubuntu 64-bit as the guest operating system. I have assigned 1024 MB of RAM to the guest and 100% CPU power is available. After installing from the iso file, it prompted me to reboot the VM, which I did. However, it is now stuck on the purple loading screen for a total of 15 minutes already, and it isn't frozen. The OS refuses to eject the iso file when I prompted it to do so via the VirtualBox command. What is the problem and how to I fix it?

Comment: Do you have virtualization enabled in "BIOS" (and does your CPU support it) ? Ir not, VirtualBox can only run 32-bit os's.

Answer (score 0):

Several paths to look into:

1. Increasing the number of processors in the settings of the mentioned machine (Right-click on the machine -> Settings -> System -> then the Processor tab).
2. Increasing the Video Memory in the Display in the Settings interface.
3. Turning off "Enable 3D Acceleration".
4. Is hardware virtualization enabled in the BIOS settings?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else ends up here and are running the virtual machine on Windows, check if Hyper-V is turned on in windows features, and if it is turn it off before trying to run the VM again. That's what worked for me.